Hyphenation added when composing or editing Discussions
On my small screen, visual line break hyphens are inserted into the text I'm composing or editing, even in the middle of URLs. See "draw-able", "an-droid.com" and "medium.-com":

(From a random Discussion I stole)
This is very confusing. Could you please not?
